# Use Alias in Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to ask how can use Alias in Select Query,

I need this

```
SELECT (Complex SubQuery) AS A, (Another Sub Query WHERE ID = A) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: I suspect the answer is to change your `Complex SubQuery` scalar expression into a table expression but it's hard to debug code we cannot see.

Comment: I agree with you. I need to make this query efficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
SELECT (Complex SubQuery) AS A, (Another Sub Query WHERE ID = A) FROM TABLE
```

You can however do this:

```
SELECT (Another Sub Query WHERE ID = A.somecolumn)
FROM table
JOIN SELECT (Complex SubQuery) AS A on (A.X = TABLE.Y)
```

Or

```
SELECT (Another Sub Query)
FROM table
WHERE table.afield IN (SELECT Complex SubQuery.otherfield)
```

The problem is that you cannot refer to aliases like this in the SELECT and WHERE clauses, because they will not have evaluated by the time the select or where part is executed.
You can also use a `having` clause, but having clauses do not use indexes and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: ?? Perhaps you meant: `WHERE ID = A.SomeColumn`

Comment: You (and the OP) are using `A` as a table alias and as a column alias (in different places).

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your query like this

```
SELECT Complex.A, (Another Sub Query WHERE ID = Complex.A)
FROM TABLE
CROSS JOIN ((Complex SubQuery) AS A) Complex
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which you can use:

```
SELECT (Complex SubQuery) AS A, (Another Sub Query WHERE ID = A) 
FROM 
TABLE MAIN
OUTER APPLY (SELECT (Complex SubQuery) AS A)
```